# Separating north, south, east and west of each parcel according to their neighborhood using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcmap, proximity

I am searching an easy way, like code, I have about 70000 parcels from the city. How can I separate north, south, east and west of each parcel according to their neighborhood?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

IF you have an advanced licence, you can do it with "[Generate Near Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Generate_Near_Table/00080000001n000000/)". This will create a table with the neighbours of the closest polygons AND the distance (discard records if distnace not equal to zero) AND the angle (it is straightforward to get the position if you know the angle: 0 to the east, 90 to the north, 180 (-180°) to the west, and -90 to the south).

EDIT: in order to clarify the relative positions, I suggest to perform a negative buffer before generating the near table. In this case, you must discard polygons when the distance is larger than 2 buffers (instead of zero).

Comment: Polygon Neighbors springs to mind but cardinality gets a bit fuzzy, perhaps west could be determined by abs(firstPoint.X - lastPoint.X) < abs(firstPoint.Y - lastPoint.Y) and X < matching centroid.X and so on.. definitely something worth scripting. The problem with *Generate Near Table* is you will get *lots* of matches that may not be adjacent - kind of difficult to filter down to the ones you want. What do you think?

Comment: I agree with @MichaelStimson that Polygon Neighbors looks like the tool to start from.

Comment: @MichaelStimson As I mentioned in my answer, you can filter down the matches based on the distance (distance must be 0), but I agree that one could start with polygon Neighbors (using the centroids to compute the angles, then, but defining N,S,W and E could be tricky in both cases e.g. 23 could be North or West).

Comment: @Polygeo this would be a good start but requires more scripting and I don't have time today. Please answer if you have some time.

Comment: Definitely needs coding but I don't think GIS SE should be viewed as a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to question: in what sector does majority of neighboring parcel area sits:

[image]

is the most robust "2D" solution.